# Intersection of 2 intervals with one variable.

Tags: measure-theory

$\ ]0,2[\cap ]z-4,z-1[ $ where $\ z\in \mathbb{R} $

*Can someone please help how to deal with such intersection?I don't know the general solution though*

I have exam tomorrow concerning such examples with not even knowing the procedure of z cases!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I suspect you must discern cases for the value of $z$ and report what form the intersection takes in these cases.

Comment: @drhab Yes i know but i tried so much with no even a logic solution. Can u help pls? I have exam tomorrow dealing with them and am not ready yet!

Comment: Consider the cases $z<1, z>6, 1\leq z \leq 4$ and $4 \leq z \leq 6$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can u pls explain how did u take the cases so that i can deal with other examples?

Comment: Take a cord of length $2$ and a cord of length $3$ (representing the intervals) and place them parallel. Note the several possibilities (no overlap, some overlap, complete overlap, et cetera) and draw conclusions for intersection and corresponding $z$.

Comment: @drhab But if the two cords don't have the same length shall I fit that of 3 and decrease it to 2 by a change of variable or I compare normally?

Comment: Example: the intersection of e.g. $(0,2)$ (a chord of length $2$) and $(-2,1)$ (a chord of length $3$ corresponding with $z=2$) is evidently $(0,1)=(0,z-1)$. Now check the cases given by Kavi.

Comment: @drhab why did u take z=2 as an example and not for ex z=4!!

Comment: Not for a particular reason. If you take $z=4$ then there is another example: the intersection $(0,2)\cap(0,3)=(0,2)$.

Comment: @drhab sorry but still dont have a touchy solution...